# How to access a variable that is inside a foreach statement who is inside an if statement in razor syntax C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, razor, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5

In a view in MVC C#, I have a variable called **items** that is inside a foreach statement, but that foreach statement is inside an if statement. I want to be able to grab the value of that variable outside of that nested statement so I can call it in another snippet of code that is in the same view a few lines down from it. How should I do that? Below is what I have so far....

```
@if (Model.isProductHasCustomField == true)
{
   //Note: In my backend db, Model.CustomFieldPipeValue has a value of Small|Medium|Large

   var size = Model.CustomFieldPipeValue.Split('|');

   <select id="CustomersDropdownSelection">
   @foreach (var items in size)
   {
       <option value="@items">@items</option>
   }
   </select>
}
    //This produces the following result in a dropdown as seen in the image below:
     //Small 
     //Medium 
     //Large
```

[image]

The code below is where I need to call that variable called **items** so that I can get each of the values passed to that attribute **data-item-custom1-options**.

How can I call it to populate **data-item-custom1-options** as those individual drop down rows. I have tried to use @items there but I get an error showing that "The name items does not exist in the current context", obviously because I can't access that variable since I am trying to call it outside of that complex nested statement.

```
@if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localhost") == true)
{
  <button id="addToCartButton"
          data-item-id="@Model.id"                                           
          data-item-name="@Model.Title"                                           
          data-item-custom1-options="I NEED THAT VARIABLE items PASSED HERE!!"                                          
          Add To Cart
  </button>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by very simply just passing this value from my model:
data-item-custom1-options="**@Model.CustomFieldPipeValue**". This already has the data structured the way I needed it and turns out I did not need to access the variable inside of the nested statement, although it would be nice to learn how to do that.

```
@if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localhost") == true)
 {
    <button id="addToCartButton"
      data-item-id="@Model.id"                                           
      data-item-name="@Model.Title"                                           
      data-item-custom1-options="@Model.CustomFieldPipeValue"                                          
      Add To Cart
    </button>
 }
```